# Is there analog Collections.singleton() / Collections.singletonList() / Collections.singletonMap() to obtain mutable collection?

Tags: java, collections, word-wrap

I know if I have element and I want to get `List`/`Set`/`Map` with this element I can invoke :

`Collections.singleton()` /  `Collections.singletonList()` / `Collections.singletonMap()`

At this case I get immutable collection(I cannot add/delete element to collection).

Is there analog to obtain mutable collection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. There would be no point for such API to exits, because you can always use the constructor that takes a collection (`new ArrayList(Collections.singleton(whatever))`)
2. If it existed it would be harmful. No sane API would allow you to choose an implementation of the new collection (eg. `LinkedList` vs. `ArrayList`) or additional parameters (like initial size).

Singleton collections are just very lean adapters for passing a single object to APIs that expect a collection. Having them mutable would defy the point entirely.

**Addendum (since, years after, I am still getting downvotes on this answer, so maybe something is not clear from the explanation) **

The singleton collections in the standard library are not "real" - they are implemented with a single attribute storing a single reference; there's no way to make them bigger. They are "fakes"; "stubs".

So why have them at all? It's a (minor) performance optimization: To create an immutable singleton collections - only one allocation is needed, whereas all the "real" collections require at least two. I.e.: even if we only store a single object in an `ArrayList`, the implementation needs to allocate an additional array. Even if we store a single object in a `LinkedList`, it needs to allocate a `Node`. And so on. No way around it.

Usually, a single additional allocation/object is not a problem, but in some performance-critical places - this will add up. So the standard library gives us a way to "create an extra-cheap stand-in for a real collection for the performance-critical places where full collection functionality is not required."

Returning a mutable collection from the singleton collections API would nullify the only reason why the API exists.

The confusion - probably - is because someone could interpret the "singleton" methods not as "algorithmical optimization" but as a "less typing and nicer code optimization". If this is your point of view, then indeed standard library could provide some sugar for "mutable singletons". It doesn't because we would be saving peanuts (literally a couple of chars, not even ten), while losing big - think about the overrides for creating different implementation (linkedList vs arrayList) or parametrizing the existing implemnetation (how would I create a singleton mutable `ArrayList` that preallocates space for 16 objects?)

Comment: I don't think that any of two points is convincing enough - ofc, we can construct a collection from another collection but it is always an unnecessary overhead; also there's nothing harmful - I want a List and I don't need to know its actual implementation - only the fact that it is a mutable one, e.g. if I pass it to Hibernate it internally may need to modify it (that's my case). Anyways, if there's a demand than it's not that pointless.

Comment: @skwisgaar Well, I don't think your use case is convincing enough. And in case of general core APIs (like Collections class) meeting demand is always less important than keeping sensible design.

Comment: It wasn't going to be convincing, I do not express my opinion as if it was the only and ultimate truth ;). In fact, there *are* APIs to achieve that despite your arguments - both guava and eclipse collections provide methods for that. I just don't think that this answer should be marked as accepted as it provides ungrounded theoretizing instead of the real answer which people are looking for.

Comment: @skwisgaar The question was about standard libraries, my answer was correct (no such method) and it contains a correct explanation of why it makes no sense (and why there's a special case for singletons). Are you sure that Guava and/or Eclipse libraries contain special methods for building mutable singleton lists? I think you are not correct - they don't (but didn't check, so you can prove me wrong; I think Eclipse collections has singleton lists which are mutable, but have fixed size, and this is clearly not what OP was asking about)

Comment: The question doesn't mention 'standard libraries', correct? Though it does states that author wants to get a mutable collection with one element. Of course, such method wouldn't be called 'singleton' as it implies single element but if we're talking about analogs - guava and eclipse are perfectly fine, e.g. as @fgb answered. So a full answer, I think, should be  that no, there are no methods in standard libraries but one can use those two to initialize a collection with single element.

Comment: @skwisgaar So... both authors of Guava and Eclipse Collections agree with my answer and do not include "mutable singleton builders" in their collections... Isn't that enough to convince you that my "opinions" are a bit more than "ungrounded theorizing"? Also, the solution I gave (new ArrayList + Collections.singleton) has (slightly) less overhead than the Guava version while introducing no additional dependencies. So it's better for most cases (and only worse for golf contests).

Comment: You're again making conclusions without reasoning them - how did you decide that guava and eclipse agree with your answer if they *do* provide a method to create mutable list with a single element in one call? Such syntax by itself ofc wouldn't justify adding an extra dependency but many projects use one/both of them for other behavior. But the most important one is that (as I stated earlier and you completely skipped it) author didn't mention that they want to use only standard libraries and don't need the method to be called exactly 'singleton'.

Comment: @skwisgaar API for building immutable singleton collections saves a lot of boilerplate and resources. API for building mutable collections of any size is a minor syntactic sugar. API for building mutable singleton collections is plain stupid. Before you proceed with accusing me of stuff, can you agree on those facts?

Comment: `This is stupid` is not a fact, it is an opinion, don't mix those two things :). If we go to strict terms - sugar is a language feature, no libs, e.g. when `a[0]` does the same as `a.first()`, in your examples both 1 and 2 save us from some boilerplate code. Also in most cases when l use singleton collection it doesn't matter much whether it is mutable or not. But again, it's not the point, the point is to read the question and provide the relevant answer (and list downsides and opinions/warnings if you think so, it's a plus but not a replacement).

Answer (score 18):

With the standard libraries you can use:

```
new ArrayList<...>(Arrays.asList(...)))
new HashSet<...>(Arrays.asList(...)))
```

These can take any number of elements as parameters. Libraries like guava have slightly more convenient methods:

```
Sets.newHashSet(...)
Lists.newArrayList(...)
Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(...))
```